# Whats the difference between k and C-p?

Tags: key-bindings

Is there any difference between the behaviour of C-p and k? The seam to be doing the same thing; moving up a line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default **in normal mode** they do the same thing. But, say, in Insert mode they don't.

This is pretty normal situation when different keys are bound to the same action. If in doubt, read the help system: `:h ctrl-p`

Comment: Ctrlp also doesnt seam to work with visual mode

Comment: @user2741831 it does for me. You may have a mapping plugin interfering (I tried with vanilla vim).

Comment: Sorry i ment select mode